# Cannot get availability_zone in spot instance by terraform state

Tags: terraform

I have

- resource `"aws_spot_instance_request" "server" {}` which starts just fine
- and need resource `"aws_ebs_volume" "spill" {}`. For EBS requires availability_zone, that I try to get from `aws_spot_instance_request.server.availability_zone`, but in .tfstate the "availability_zone" of server is null. That leads to:

> Error: Reference to undeclared resource.

How can I get the availability_zone of spot instance?

Answer (score 1):

From the looks of it, the availability zone attribute isn't exported from `aws_spot_instance_request`. You can see the list of available attributes [here](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/spot_instance_request#attributes-reference)

I would perhaps look at using the `aws_spot_fleet_request` resource with a target capacity of 1. This way you can achieve the same effect and use a launch configuration to specify the availability zone, and then reference it in the attributes (as shown [here](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/spot_fleet_request#overrides))